# Get a circular Layout in SWT

Tags: java, layout, swt

I need to create SWT arranged in a circular manner something similar to the numbers in a circular clock. Is this is possible in SWT layouts.

Can the layouts be customized?

Comment: You can write your own layout by extending the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout` class, but this does require a fair amount of understanding of how layouts work.

Comment: You *could* "approximate" a circular layout by using a `GridLayout` and filling the "gaps" with `Label`s.

Comment: What is it btw that you want to arrange in a circular fashion? Actual SWT `Widget`s? Or is it just text? In that case you could use Draw2d or Zest.

Comment: Hi Baz !! I want to arrange buttons/labels/textbox

Comment: Well, the you'll probably have to write your own layout (as @greg-449 suggested).